# How to code in Markdown and convert to HTML correctly?

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, markdown, file-conversion

The Markdown code below works correctly on the Jupyter Notebook, but when I open the HTML converted file (via Jupyter Notebook: File>Download as>HTML) there is an error related to the interpretation of \\. How to fix to convert to HTML? I believe there is some HTML inline tag to solve my problem...

```
|Python Operator|Description|Example|
|:-------------:|:----------|:-----:|
|+|Addition or adds a positive sign to one operand| +1 + 1|
|-|Subtraction or adds a negative sign to one operand| -1 + 1|
|\*|Multiplication| 2\*3|
|\\|Division| 12/5|
|\*\*|Exponentiation|2\*\*3|
|\\\ |Floor division| 12\\\7|
|%|Modulus|12%7|
```

My horrible solution was to use HTML inline and change the style attribute in all cells...

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th style='text-align:center'>Python Operator</th><th style='text-align:left'>Description</th><th>Example</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td style='text-align:center'>+</td><td style='text-align:left'>Addition or adds a positive sign to one operand</td><td style='text-align:center'>+1 + 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td style='text-align:center'>-</td><td style='text-align:left'>Subtraction or adds a negative sign to one operand</td><td style='text-align:center'>-1 + 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td style='text-align:center'>*</td><td style='text-align:left'>Multiplication</td><td style='text-align:center'>2*3</td></tr>
        <tr><td style='text-align:center'>\</td><td style='text-align:left'>Division</td><td style='text-align:center'>12/5</td></tr>
        <tr><td style='text-align:center'>**</td><td style='text-align:left'>Exponentiation</td><td style='text-align:center'>2**3</td></tr>
        <tr><td style='text-align:center'>\\</td><td style='text-align:left'>Floor division</td><td style='text-align:center'>12\\7</td></tr>
        <tr><td style='text-align:center'>%</td><td style='text-align:left'>Modulus</td><td style='text-align:center'>12%7</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a less verbose form?

Comment: How are you converting to HTML? Note that math is not a standard feature of Markdown. While Jupiter Notebook includes support, most Markdown implementations do not, at least not by default. If you let us know which tool you are using and how you are using it, perhaps we can provide direction on how to enable math support for that tool (if it has support).

Comment: To convert to HTML in Jupyter Notebook: File>Download as>HTML.

Comment: I believe there is some HTML inline tag to solve my problem...

Comment: Thanks. I edited my ask, try now :)